# Check for specific Object in an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, game-development

I'm having difficulty creating an if statement to check for an object in an array. If the if statement is triggered i just want it to hide something basically.

```
const x = document.getElementById('Music');

let state = {}

//this is a game where the state is set based on which option you select//
state = Object.assign(state, option.setState)


if(state.includes(keypad)) {
      x.style.display = "none"
};
```

Thank you, hopefully that's enough information - i've tried a few other variations but to no avail :( as follows:

```
if(Object.values(state).includes("keypad")) {
     x.style.display = "none"
};


if(state.some("keypad")) {
     x.style.display = "none"};

if (state.filter(function(e) { return e.Name === 'keypad'; }).length > 0) {
    x.style.display = "none"

if(state.some(currentState === keypad )) {
    x.style.display = "none";
        
};

if((currentState) = currentState.keypad) {
  x.style.display = "none";
        
};
```

Edit 29/10 - More Info:

Thanks William - keypad does not exist at the start of the game - is this a problem? - i figured if the if statement isn't true it just won't execute?

I'm thinking perhaps this line is a problem wherein the key for each element in state is deleted?:

```
Object.keys(state).forEach(key => state[key] === undefined && delete state[key])
```

option.setState references a const array which includes the game text, room number, image to go on screen.etc, here's an example:

```
 function startGame() {
    state = {}
    items = {}
    showTextNode(1)
}

const textNodes = [{
        id: 1,
        room_id: 1,
        text: '"ZZZZzzzzZZZZZZzzzzzzzzzzZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"',
        options: [{
                text: 'Wake up',
                
                ///item: {item: true, itemName: "item"},
                nextText: 2
            }

        ]

    },

    {
        id: 2,
        room_id: 2,
        text: 'You wake up in your bunk. \n"I dont feel good this morning....i need to get out of bed."',
        options: [{
                text: 'Look at alarm clock',
                setState: { test: true},
                setItems: { item1: "test"},
                nextText: 3
            },
            {
                text: 'Get out of bed',
                nextText: 4

            }
        ]

    },

    {
        id: 3,
        room_id: 3,
        text: 'Its 3:34am',
        options: [{
                text: 'Get out of bed',
                setState: { gun: true },
                setItems: { item2: "gun"},
                nextText: 4
            },

        ]
    },

    {
        id: 4,
        room_id: 4,
        text: 'Its dark, the automatic lights should have come on...',
        options: [{
                text: 'look at keypad',
                setState: { keypad: true},
                nextText: 8
            },
            {
                text: 'Look out window',
                nextText: 5
            },
            
            {
                text: 'Put your uniform on',
                setState: { uniform: true},
                setItems: { item3: "uniform"},
                nextText: 5

            },
            {
                text: 'Open door and \nleave your cell',
                setState: { door: true },
                nextText: 6

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        id: 5,
        room_id: 4,
        text: 'Its dark, the automatic lights should have come on...',
        options: [{
                text: 'Look at Keypad',
                setState: { keypad: true },
                nextText: 8
            },
            {
                text: 'Look out window',
                nextText: 7
            },
            
           
            {
                text: 'Open door and \nleave your cell',
                setState: { door: true },
                nextText: 6

            }
        ]
    },

    
]



startGame()
```

Thanks for the quick responses, you guys are the best, been working on this for a few hours now ha ha

[game screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqfxL.jpg)

The fix: Thank you for the replies everyone - apologies this game im making is quite convoluted at this point. So it turns out i was mixing up arrays and object arrays.

Since state is an object array i used:

```
function check (){
if(Object.keys(state).includes("keypad"))
  x.style.display = "none";
   console.log('fired'); 
}
```

I'm not currently trying to work out how i can check to see if keypad is keypad:true or keypad:false and show/hide something based on that - however im half way there so i think thats enough for one day.

Comment: Many of the options you're using should work fine, if indeed the keypad object is in fact present on the state. I suspect it isn't - it could be that you have a separate instance of the state object populated on the state.

It would be helpful to know more about the keypad object itself, and the other objects that may exist in the setState object you're assigning to the state object.

It would be useful to debug the code or output some console.log() statements to view the contents of the variables, as they're possibly not exactly what you're expecting them to be.

Comment: what does `option.setState` reference? an object? a string? Also `state` is an object, but you are trying to call array methods on it: `includes()`, `some()`, `filter()`

Comment: It is hard to bring the pieces of information together. You gave "room 2" as example, but it is an incomplete snippet from probably an object, but it currently is invalid syntax. It would be much more useful if you would add a *minimal* but *complete* `option` value (array/object), and then would clearly specify what the expected output/behaviour is for it. Your code certainly has errors, but it is hard to see what you actually want as result.

Comment: Can you give 2 examples for `state` (one you want to display and the other no) and the result you expect for each of them?

Comment: Apologies @trincot - I've added more information with regards to the textNodes object array

Comment: @djcaesar9114 - the player state changes throughout the game - so here i'm just trying to trigger an if statement if "keypad" is present in the state Array

Comment: @pilchard - ah thank you, this must be why those methods are not working - i will do some reading on how to check if an object contains another object

Comment: But what is "keypad"? A key of an object of the array? A value? Again, give 2 examples of states: one with the keypad condition and the other without. Like this, it's hard for us to understand as we can interpret your problem in various ways.

Comment: @djcaesar9114  As i understand it - keypad is a value of the textNodes object array which is assigned to the state object when the option it is attached to is selected by the player

Comment: Sorry, if you don't put the 2 examples I asked for, I won't be able to help you.